# How can i get subtraction of one max column and one min column?

Tags: mysql, sql

First of all , i'm sorry if my title made things more complicated but here is the thing that i want. I want to get subtraction of two columns. My first column is maximum score on Math who got from Men and the second column is minimum score on Math who got from Women. So here is what i'm trying to do but fail. **Ps. stu_gender is in student table , mat is in notes table**

```
    select max(mat) from students,scores where stu_gender = "Male"
  - (select min(mat) from students,scores where stu_gender = "Female")
```

It gives me this error

```
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Male'
```

So how can i get what i want? I'm looking for your answers and thanks for your any comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the result of each select is a table, `-` means set minus. You can do it likes the following:

```
select (max(mat) - (select min(mat) from students,scores where stu_gender = "Female")) 
from students,scores where stu_gender = "Male"
```

Or:

```
select(max(r.mat) - (select min(r.mat) from r where r.stu_gender = "Female"))
from (select * from students,scores) as r
where r.stu_gender = "Male"
```